# RStudio heatmap: color gradient

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

I'm trying to design a heatmap to see the difference in gene expression between two cell types. However, when it comes to MALAT1, I am not able to find the right color gradient to highlight the difference since it's very small.

Here's my data:
[image]

This is what I've tried so far:

```
col2<-colorRampPalette(c("blue3","blue","dodgerblue3","dodgerblue2","white","orangered2","red2","red3","red4"))(300)
    
heatmap.2(tab4, trace = "none", density.info='none',margins = c(7,5),Rowv = TRUE, Colv = FALSE, cexRow = 0.7, cexCol = 1.2, col= col2, scale="column")
```

I thought adding more colors would help tbh.

Result:

[image]

As you can see, MALAT1 and BEST1 are presented with the same color. Is there a way to fix this? I also tried scaling by rows, but then I either get blue or red as color - there's no gradient.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the issue is. Shouldn't they have a similar shading of colour? Their values are fairly close to one another across the 2 columns and are both outliers to all the other rows.

Comment: yes, but my goal is to show the difference between the two columns, even if it's small. I tried to use scale = "row", but then I only get red or blue as color, no shades. Is there a way to do so?